# Complex one-line conditional checksum definitions

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Taking up this code:

```
typedef enum CHECKSUM { DENY = 0, ALLOW = 1 } checksum;
#define terminal(x, str) static checksum* terminal_##x; { if(!strcmp(#str, "static")) { static checksum local = ALLOW; terminal_##x = &local; } else { checksum local = DENY; terminal_##x = &local; }  }
```

What I want that code to do is define a macro function with two parameters `x` for name and `str` for a specific type. The macro function declares a `static checksum*` with the name `terminal_` concatenated with the name `x`. Then it opens a new scope and stringify the specific type `str` and use a `strcmp` to check if it equals `static`. If so.. then it declares a variable type `static checksum`, initialized with `ALLOW` and makes the declared pointer to point to it, if it is not equal then it declares a variable type `checksum`, initialized with `DENY` and set the pointer to point to it.
Then we can call the macro like that:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(*terminal_name == ALLOW) { terminal(name, static) if(i > 200) { *terminal_name = DENY; } i++; }

    return 0;
    // Note that this is only an example usage. The real usage of this is far more long and complicated.
}
```

The code is well compiled on C89 and it causes no errors nor warnings. On a first view.. it works.
But as you can see by yourself.. it looks really suspicious.

Is that the correct way I am doing it?

*Please ask if you are in trouble understanding something.*

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if the macro is reasonable or a bad idea without knowing more about your program.

Stylistically, you can use backslashes to split the macro up into multiple lines. That'll make it a lot more readable and less "suspicious".

```
#define terminal(x, str)                   \
    static checksum* terminal_##x;         \
    {                                      \
        if (!strcmp(#str, "static")) {     \
            static checksum local = ALLOW; \
            terminal_##x = &local;         \
        }                                  \
        else {                             \
            checksum local = DENY;         \
            terminal_##x = &local;         \
        }                                  \
    }
```

Using `strcmp` to decide whether to use `static` or not really rubs me the wrong way. That's a runtime check influencing a compile-time decision. I would suggest making two separate macros, say `LOCAL_TERMINAL` and `STATIC_TERMINAL`, rather than keying off of a macro argument.

```
#define LOCAL_TERMINAL (x)        checksum terminal_##x = DENY
#define STATIC_TERMINAL(x) static checksum terminal_##x = ALLOW
```

Comment: Thanks for remending me about backslashes. But I am not asking if this is a good idea or not. Since i am working on it, and even posting it here for that matter i think it worths. I am not trying to reinvent C.

Comment: If you say this works, and you're not asking if it's a good idea or not... what *is* your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Meanwhile i did some tests. Writing globally: `terminal(mouse, local)` then checking locally with: `if(terminal_mouse == ALLOW)..` it returns error for invalid memory area. My questions stands here. I didn't want this to happen. So i am doing something wrong. EDIT: wait a second. I am stupid. It shouldn't be declared globally because then `static` does the opposite.

Comment: It seems that the pointer don't needs to be `static` for the script to work. So why it returns memory error when i use a globally declared pointer that points to a statical local variable?

Comment: i don't want to do this. Is there any way to make a global pointer to point to a local variable? It crashes if i don't do `terminal(name, static)` Also you are wrong. the `strcmp` is being parsed through the interprter at firsts, requested by the preprocessor.

Comment: "Is there any way to make a global pointer to point to a local variable?" Yes, but the pointer's only valid as long as the local variable is in scope. When you exit the block it's in, the pointer is no longer valid. That's a reason I recommend my solution, because you don't want to declare the local variable in a block that immediately exits. --- "Also you are wrong." No, I'm not. If you want me to explain what I meant in more detail, I'm happy to answer any questions you have about why I said what I said.

Comment: Yes but, shall we do this in chat?